# Change image width and height based on screen size

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I'm writing a web app, and I need a large image at the top of the screen. I want the image to be stretched across the full width of the screen, but if that makes the image too large to fit within the top 80% of the screen, I want it to be stretched vertically across the top 80%. I've tried `width="100%"`, which looks great on my phone, but much too big on my laptop, and `height=80%` which does the reverse. `width="100%" height="100%"` messes up the aspect ratio :(

Comment: have you tried using width=80% some sort of that kind attrbute?

Comment: I've tried that but depending on which is less I want to apply one of width and height

Comment: Why not use add a class to the image and add a media query in your CSS that affects the width and height of your viewport? See the documentation on [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) on MDN.

Comment: I don't necessarily know the width and height so I would need to get this with PHP. Not quite so elegant, but better than quite a few things I've done with HTML which it wasn't made to do

Comment: You can get width and height in javascript.